# How Do I activate StreetPass on 3DS Sound?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I don't know how to activate Streetpass on 3DS sound.  How do I transfer a song from my computer to the SD card?

Comment: yay! This question has got me a "Notable Question" badge! Now to get the golden version...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To activate StreetPass for the 3DS Sound app, tap on the <kbd>StreetPass</kbd> button on the lower left of the touch screen. The lower part of the screen will have a button that says <kbd>StreetPass Off</kbd>. Tap that and then tap the <kbd>On</kbd> button and <kbd>Confirm</kbd> to turn StreetPass on.

This requires that you have at least one song in the StreetPass playlist. To achieve this, first you must put a song on your SD card from another device, such as a computer. To do this, insert your SD card into an SD card slot if your computer has one or a card reader peripheral reader otherwise. Then the SD card should appear as a drive in your computer, and you can copy files to it the same way you can with a flash drive or generally moving files around in your file system browser. The music files have to be of one of these four formats: `.mp3`, `.m4a`, `.mp4`, or `.3gp` and they have to be in a folder.

Then put the SD card back in the 3DS and open the Sound app. In the app, navigate through the folders to a song and select it. There will be a button on the bottom right that says <kbd>Add...</kbd>, which you can click to add the song to a playlist. Once you add a song to the StreetPass playlist, the option to activate StreetPass will become available.

Comment: So how do I get another song from a computer to my SD card?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you say "another" do you mean that you already have a song on your SD card?

Comment: No.. I want to know how to get a song from a computer, rather than the ones I have already recorded from my 3ds.

Comment: That is what my answer attempted to describe. What part of it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: How do I transfer a song from my computer to the SD card?

Comment: I added an edit that might help explain things.

Comment: Oh no!!! My computer does not have an SD card slot!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just look for any songs on your computer anywhere. Left-click the mouse and then press save as, name it, find it, and move it to the SD card. There are sometimes SD card slots on the tower of a computer.